# putting PHP DB location results to one single google map

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

i have a location values stored in my Mysql DB, i want to 
    retrieve those many locations to one google map so that all the locations i 
    selected will pop up on the single map. here is sample code i have found in 
    here but this code prints all the locations on different google maps. for me 
    i want only single map with all the locations being marked on the map.

```
// set up variables
$output = '';
$map_width = '600';     // map frame width
$map_height = '350';    // map frame height

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $location = stripslashes($row['location']);
    $city = stripslashes($row['city']);

    // compile resulting html with variables and db results
    $output .= "<iframe width='" . 
            $map_width . "' height='" . $map_height . 
            "' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' 
            marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='"; 

    // the original search query (googlemaps api uses "q=...")          
    $output .= "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" . $location;

    // location to refine the query (googlemaps api uses "near=...")
    $output .= "&amp;near=" . $city;    

    // set map to 'terrain'                     
    $output .= "&amp;t=p";  

    //zoom level            
    $output .= "&amp;z=15";                         
    $output .= "&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";  

    $output .= "<br /><small><a href='" . $location . 
            "&amp;output=source' target='_blank' 
            style='color:#0000FF;text-align:left'>
            View Larger Map</a></small>";   
}

// print it all out
echo $output;
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: So, where is the problem? Can you generate a URL that does the job by hand (without PHP) and post it?

Comment: This tutorial does just this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: the problem is the while loop is generating one map for each location.i.e for eg. if i have three locations fetched from my DB, 3 different maps locating each $location variable, will be generated. my question is, how to have the 3 locations in one single map in spite of having 3 different maps